# How do you get final outputed HTML in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get entire HTML source of a post page of WordPress for that scraping meta-keywords from the HTML.(then want to use the keywords as Twitter hashtags.)

I think up to use `callback` like the following PHP script but It mistaken idea.

```
function callback($buffer) {

  // scraping meta and var_dump it
    $meta_tags = getMetaTags($buffer);
    echo var_dump($meta_tags) ; // Not outputed, also not to get value as well

    return $buffer ;

}
ob_start("callback");
```

How do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to get "the entire page worth of HTML" is to use the [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook, it's often used for "run-time find & replace" methods. If I ever need to use it, I just use it in an [Anonymous Function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        // Do whatever to $buffer - it contains the entire page's HTML output

        return $buffer;
    });
});
```